# Popup without button Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I am writing a Health application in Xamarin. I want to show a popup without button when user login and says "User valid. Redirecting to Welcome page in 5 secs." but without button.

```
var isVaild = AreCredentialsCorrect(user);
if (isVaild)
{
    await DisplayAlert("Register", "Valid user. Redirecting to Welcome page in 5 secs.", "OK");
    App.IsUserLoggedIn = true;
    OnAppearing();
    await Navigation.PopAsync();
}
else
{
    await DisplayAlert("Alert", "Not a valid entry.", "OK");
    passw.Text = string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: a popup that automatically dismisses without user interaction is typically called a "Toast".  There are a number of plugins for Forms that will do this, including https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs

Comment: I'm looking it now, thanks for reply :)

Comment: @Jason also is added to https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit#toast

Comment: That sounds more like an [activityindicator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/activityindicator) or [Progress prompts in Acr.Userdialog](https://devlinduldulao.pro/how-to-use-acr-userdialogs/). Or you can fake one with Grid layout.